# Кто поможет нарисовать вот такой треугольник на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто поможет нарисовать вот такой треугольник на JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align:center">#<br>**<br>*#*....</div>
```

```js
var line = 15;
var star = 1;
var space = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < line; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < space; j++) {
    document.write('&nbsp');
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < star; k++) {
    if (!(i % 2) && (k > star / 2 - 1) && (k < star / 2)) {
      document.write('#')
    } else {
      document.write('*')
    }
  }
  star++;
  space--;
  document.write('<br>');
}
```

Comment: только на javascript без html

Comment: Отображать-то все равно придется в html

Comment: а без html никак...вот у меня получился так

Comment: var line = 15;
var star = 1;
var space = 100;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < line ; i++){
    for( var j = 0 ; j < space ; j++){
        document.write("&nbsp");
    }
    for (var k = 0 ; k < star ; k++){
        document.write("*")
    }
    star = star + 1;
    space = space - 1;
    document.write("<br>")
}

Comment: дополнил вставкой хэша